# PHP waiting for script to finish before echoing any output issue

Tags: php, vps

So recently...

My VPS had an automatic update and this screwed up the way my PHP scripts were last ran. Last time, I didn't even need to use ob_flush or any of the output buffering related solutions to see my output before the script finished. It just simply worked.

> This is the automatic software update:

```
    The following software were updated during Automatic Cron Updates:
    phpList 3.3.1 - Successful
    poMMo 16.1 - Successful
```

> The logs of the Updates are as follows:

```
WordPress
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Joomla 2.5
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

AbanteCart
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

PrestaShop
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Joomla
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Drupal 7
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpBB
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

SMF
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Magento 1.9
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

WHMCS
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

MyBB
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Gallery
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Open Blog
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Piwigo
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

AEF
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

osTicket
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpList
Versions dont match.....Needs Update
Fetching Latest File......Saved the Latest File
Mirror : s4.softaculous.com
Unzipping the files......Unzipped Successfully
Deleting previous files......Done

Zikula
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

kPlaylist
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

poMMo
Versions dont match.....Needs Update
Fetching Latest File......Saved the Latest File
Mirror : s2.softaculous.com
Unzipping the files......Unzipped Successfully
Deleting previous files......Done

HESK
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Serendipity
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Dotclear
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Mibew Messenger
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Drupal 6
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Revive Adserver
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

WebCalendar
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

DokuWiki
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Podcast Generator
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

SquirrelMail
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

BlackNova Traders
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

PunBB
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

WeBid
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Help Center Live
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Shadows Rising
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Claroline
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

PHPfileNavigator
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Geeklog
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

dotProject
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpOnline
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Advanced Guestbook
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Multiplayer Checkers
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpLD
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Webinsta Maillist
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Lazarus
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

ccMail
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Booked
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

LittlePoll
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Moodle 2.6
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Sales Syntax
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

BellaBook
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

PmWiki
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Mautic
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpESP
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Word Search Puzzle
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpBook
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

phpicalendar
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Aardvark Topsites
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Impleo
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

VX Guestbook
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

ExoPHPDesk
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

RicarGBooK
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Raphael
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Rico
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing

Trac
Current Version is Latest Version......Continuing
```

So I went to my PHP ini and checked if my values changed, and I believe they did, so I changed my max_exec time, memory limits, output_buffering to off, etc. The script still waited for everything to be completed before it output anything. So I decided to start using flush in my scripts. I started up a test script and wrote the following:

```
<?php 
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    ini_set('max_execution_time' ,0); 
    ini_set('set_memory_limit', -1);
    ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
    set_time_limit(0);
    while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_implicit_flush();
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo 'Hello';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(5);
    echo 'World!';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
 ?>
```

I used every solution in the book to try to fix it and guess what...?
It still waited 5 seconds to say Hello World instead of saying Hello, waiting 5 seconds and then outputting world.

PHP Version : 5.6.30

I'd love to access my PHP scripts through my browser, but I might be forced to use CLI because this isn't working.

Damn it, I'll just paste my PHP.ini file for any PHP tech wizard to maybe find a kink with.

```
http://pastebin.com/cm1gjt9W
```

EDIT: So I paused CloudFlare and then resumed it... and it's working fine now. I don't understand.

Comment: Your example works here. Output Hello, then wait 5 secs, then output World! (HelloWorld!).

Comment: That's the thing... it's not working for me. Like what is going on :o

Wait... could CloudFlare have anything to do with this?